# Slack APP users.lookup returning "missing_scope"

Tags: c#, asp.net, slack-api

I am new to Slack.
I have:

- created a Slack app.
- clicked on "OAuth & Permission"
- selected the scopes needed by my app.
- **On the User Token Scopes**:

  - `users:read`
  - `users:read.email`
- **On the Bot Token Scopes**:

  - `users:read`
  - `users:read.email`
- Reinstalled it to Workspace.
- Approved by the Slack Administrator.

I sent a GET request to `https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail?email=MyEmail`

I got the response with a Json:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"users:read.email","provided":"identify,chat:write"}
```

I used the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class from `System.Net.Http` namespace.
I tried the request with both Tokens "User" and "Bot".

Is there something I am missing?

Does that application needs to be created by an administrator?